Did matriarchal form of society exist in Europe during the French Revolution? (Reference: A tale of two cities.)
Set during the French Revolution,  A Tale of Two Cities by Charles Dickens follows Charles Darnay, an aristocrat who renounces his title and moves to England to live as an ordinary man, rejecting the injustices of the aristocracy.
However, when he returns to France to help a family servant, he is arrested because of his noble lineage.
This is a passage from the abridged version of the story:

When they finally got to Paris, Defarge took Charles to a prison. People were lying on the floor, waiting to be sentenced.
A guard turned to Defarge and said, "Is this Evrémonde's nephew?".
"Yes," Defarge said. "This is him.".
"Show me your papers, Evrémonde!" the guard said.
"I will," Charles said. "But I'm called Darnay. My mother was an Evrémonde, not me.".
"You are sentenced to prison at La Force," the guard said.
"To prison? What for?" Charles exclaimed. "I haven't done anything.".
*"We have got new laws,"" the guard said. "Things have changed since you were here. You are an aristocrat and your family were cruel and oppressive.".
"Yes, they were," answered Charles. "But I wasn't like them. I gave up my title and left the country..

My query:.
As per my knowledge, France had a patriarchal  society during this period.
How did Charles Darnay inherit the Evrémonde title and face punishment due to his mother’s family, even though titles and responsibilities are usually passed through the father’s side in a patriarchal society?

History SE question.

How is this an English language problem? Wikipedia can answer your first question.

@Mari-LouA As per my knowledge, France had a patriarchal society during this period. So I am unable to understand the story. Edited and included

Or Literature SE. It's a long time since I read the book, but presumably the revolutionaries were after anyone with aristocratic connections.

Despite the edit it's still not an English language problem.  Charles Darnay, …, hopes to honor his mother's dying wish by ameliorating the wrongs the family has caused. When his uncle [Marquis St. Evrémonde ] laughs at this, Charles renounces his rights to the Evrémonde title and lands, Wikipedia Charles at the time did not have a noble title, which he would have (presumably) inherited after his uncle's death, his mother was already dead.

Later, Darnay succeeds his uncle as Marquis when the latter is stabbed to death in his sleep by a French revolutionary. source: Wikipedia As I mentioned earlier, Wikipedia can answer your first question.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a question of French History, not Learning English

@JamesK Please explain how a novel can be called "history". Many schools have lessons (in English subject) based on the novel.

Ok then "[literature.se]  This is a historical novel.  It is a fictionalised account of the history of the French Revolution, written long after the events it describes.

In A Tale of Two Cities (Charles Dickens' original story), Charles Darnay is the son of the Marquis St. Evrémonde, making him a member of the Evrémonde family through his father, not his mother. His mother was married into the Evrémonde family, and Darnay inherits the title through his paternal lineage.
It was his mother's dying wish that he should correct the wrongs the family had caused.
The following lines were added by the writer who simplified the original text for the UK publisher:
"But I'm called Darnay. My mother was an Evrémonde, not me."

I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about French history as the background for a story, not about the English language itself.

BTW, "to my knowledge" would be much more idiomatic than "As per my knowledge".
